# how to identify outlook admin email with python

Tags: python, office365, exchange-server

How can I verify if an outlook email is an admin without having the password?

Autodiscover doesn't provide the infomation.

```py
import requests
user_agent = 'Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Outlook 16.0.12026; Pro)'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent, 'Accept': "application/json"}
email = "user@example.com"
r = requests.get('https://outlook.office365.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.json/v1.0/{}?Protocol=autodiscoverv1'.format(email), headers=headers, allow_redirects=False, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: you need to be more specific in your question?  What type of admin are you trying to determine if the user is one of them?